# PIC32 c32 1.12, Malloc hangs application

Tags: malloc, pic

I am compiling the following code for a PIC32 with C32 v1.12 using MPLabX IDE. 
The code compiles find but hangs on `malloc()`, it does not seem to matter what size I am attempting to malloc it always hangs.

By hang I mean the debugger becomes unresponsive and the application has to be manually restarted before it will continue.

```
#define SAFE_DELETE( x ) { if(x != NULL ) { free(x); x=NULL ; } } 

BOOL Test_Malloc() {

    int *ptr = NULL ;
    ptr = (int*)malloc(10 * sizeof (int)); // With a cast
    if( ptr != NULL ) {
        SAFE_DELETE( ptr );
        return TRUE ;
    }
    return FALSE ; 
}
```

My question is ;

- How do I malloc memory on a PIC32 with C32 v1.12?

Comment: What is `SAFE_DELETE`? Are you 100% sure it's the `malloc` that hangs and not the code after it? What is the project's heap size set to? Make sure it's at least 4KB greater than the amount of memory you may need.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Added SAFE_DELETE definition to the example source code. Yes I am sure that the code hangs on the malloc not the SAFE_DELETE, How do I check the projects heap size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to set your project's heap size at least 4KB greater than the maximum amount of dynamic memory you might ever need. You have to guesstimate what what the C library might need if you call functions that themselves call `malloc`. It's not quite an exact science.

See this [Microchips forum thread](http://www.microchip.com/forums/m483626-print.aspx) for more details.

Comment: It looks like the default heap size is zero. you have to specificity set the heap size if you want to use malloc()

Comment: for more information on how to set the heap size google "MPLAB C Compiler for PIC32MX MCUs User’s Guide" section "5.5 HEAP USAGE"